# SwiftUI how to select text in TextField

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

SwiftUI, How can I select text in TextField as we can in UIKit `UITextField` `selectAll()` or range of text

```
if let textRange = myTextView.selectedTextRange {
    let selectedText = myTextView.text(in: textRange)
}
```

Comment: Many of the SwiftUI components lack the full feature set of `UIKit` classes. You probably need to subclass `UITextField` and use `UIViewRepresentable`